# Functional difference between if-then and command group

Tags: bash, if-statement, sh, short-circuiting

Is there any functional advantage of using a simple if-then statement such as

```
if [ … ]; then
do
```

over using short-circuit list evaluators with command groups such as

```
[ … ] && {
}
```

Of course, if-then is the standard way of writing it, but is there any actual difference/advantage from a functional point of view?

Using `()` instead of `{}` would spawn a new subshell, thus creating a new scope for variables inside the if-then block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with your example, but the commonly seen

```
condition && foo || bar
```

is not the same as

```
if condition
then
  foo
else
  bar
fi
```

In the former case, `bar` will run not only if `condition` fails, but if `foo` fails.

Comment: Would be the same as the clumsy `condition && { foo; false; } || bar`, right?

Comment: If you mean `condition && { foo; true; } || bar` then yes.

Comment: um yes, I meant to write `condition && { foo; :; } || bar`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if that is right. Don't do shells short-circuit evaluation? So `condition && foo || bar` is basically the same as `(condition && foo) || bar` (operator precedence) which means that if `condition` is false, `foo` will not be executed anyway. Or does boolean evaluation work differently in common shells?

Comment: @knittl Yes, the problem is when `condition` is true, but `foo` is false. When `condition` is false or `foo` is true, it's all good.